# Mysql 64 bit on a cloud server with 2 GB RAM

Tags: mysql, database

Apologies for the naive question in advance - Trying to test mysql 64 bit with our cloud server. The cloud server has windows 2008 64 bit installed on it with 2 GB RAM. Would mysql 64 bit be ok with the 2 GB or would we face problems while testing?

The rationale is to scale up to 8 GB of RAM once we have tested and fixed the bugs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

64-bit MySQL will run just fine with 2 GB of RAM. I've run it on 128 MB Linux systems before -- it does require somewhat more memory than the 32-bit version, but not by much.